# Where are JSHint errors logged?

Tags: gruntjs, jshint

I just started messing around with Grunt. I have a basic implementation running successfully, minifying my code and running JSHint.

It says 0 files lint free, which I've gathered means that all of the files it's checking have lint.

However, I've been googling for an hour, and somehwat incredibly, cannot figure out where the hell these errors are being saved.

Do I need to specify a logfile in the grunt config? I don't see anything like that in the JSHint or grunt documentation.

Gruntfile below, taken pretty much straight from Grunt's "Getting Started". I pulled out qunit because I don't currently have any tests -

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({

    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    concat: {
      options: {
        // define a string to put between each file in the concatenated output
        separator: ';'
      },
      dist: {
        // the files to concatenate
        src: ['spin/**/*.js'],
        // the location of the resulting JS file
        dest: 'dist/<%= pkg.name %>.js'
      }
    },

    uglify: {
      options: {
        // the banner is inserted at the top of the output
        banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("dd-mm-yyyy") %> */\n'
      },
      dist: {
        files: {
          'dist/<%= pkg.name %>.min.js': ['<%= concat.dist.dest %>']
        }
      }
    },

    jshint: {
      // define the files to lint
      files: ['gruntfile.js', 'src/**/*.js', 'test/**/*.js'],
      // configure JSHint (documented at http://www.jshint.com/docs/)
      options: {
          // more options here if you want to override JSHint defaults
          "curly": true,
  "eqnull": true,
  "eqeqeq": true,
  "undef": true,
        globals: {
          jQuery: true,
          console: true,
          module: true
        }
      }
    },

    watch: {
      files: ['<%= jshint.files %>'],
      tasks: ['jshint']
    }

  });

      grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
      grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
      grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
      grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');

      grunt.registerTask('test', ['jshint']);

      grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint', 'concat', 'uglify']);

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0 files lint free does not mean that you have files which have errors, it means that zero files are checked!

the jshint-task will output errors to your console (including file, linenumber and column)

thats where you specify your files to check:

```
files: ['gruntfile.js', 'src/**/*.js', 'test/**/*.js'],
```

if you change 'gruntfile.js' to 'Gruntfile.js' (case sensitive!) it should check your gruntfile (which you of course already have).

Comment: Yep, this seems like it will work. Stupid mistake. Do you know if there IS a way to specify a logfile, instead of the results just dumping in the console?

Comment: So yep, this worked. I feel silly for not catching that. But yeah, it's logging like thousands and thousands of lines. Do I need to just de-lint my files individually until they're closer to par, or maybe I can specify library files to ignore, or just make a decent list of my "acceptable" lint?

Comment: your first step could be using a the grunt-beautify plugin: https://github.com/pix/grunt-beautify